# How to adjust table header when saving dataframe to excel using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

The objective is to save a df as xlsx format using the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
list_me = [['A','A','A','A','A','B','C','D','D','D','D'],
               ['TT','TT','UU','UU','UU','UU','UU','TT','TT','TT','TT'],
               ['5','2','1','1','1','40','10','2','2','2','2'],
               ['1','1','1','2','3','3','1','2','2','2','1']]

df = DataFrame (list_me).transpose()
df.columns = ['Name','Activity','Hour','Month']
df_tab=pd.crosstab(df.Name, columns=[df.Month, df.Activity], values=df.Hour, aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
df_tab.reset_index ( level=0, inplace=True )
df_tab.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

The code work fine and outputted xlsx as below:

[image]

However, I notice adding index on the first column separate the text `Month, Activity, Name` into separate columns.

May I know whether there is a build-in setting within Pandas that can produce the output as below?

[image]

Thanks in advance

p.s.: Please ignore the yellow line, it just to indicate there should be a blank row.